# Get supported filetype extension from string

Tags: php

I'm trying make a `get_extension()` function return the file extension if it is included in the array of supported file types. Right now it doesn't return anything.

I've tested my `contains()` function and it seems to work like I want but I can't figure out why `get_extension()` isn't working right. Is it a problem with how I declared my array?

```
$supported = ['.md', '.txt', '.html', '.pdf'];

function get_extension($name){
  foreach ($supported as $type){
    if(contains($name, $type)){
      return $type;
    }
  }
}

function contains($outer, $inner){
  return strpos($outer, $inner) !== false;
}

echo get_extension("spencer.txt");
```

Comment: if extension not found in array, what suppose to be returned, false ?

Comment: **Scope** ___Scope___ _Scope_ `get_extension()` has no idea what `$supported` is Either pass it as a parameter or in this case I would probably define `$supported` inside the function

Comment: Ah... I see now. That actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scope** ***Scope*** *Scope* `get_extension()` has no idea what `$supported` is Either pass it as a parameter or in this case I would probably define `$supported` inside the function

```
function get_extension($name){
  $supported = ['.md', '.txt', '.html', '.pdf'];

  foreach ($supported as $type){
    if(contains($name, $type)){
      return $type;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathinfo` method with `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` flag, it will return you filename extension.

Thereafter you can pass your supportedextensions array to function, which will return true false by check extension exists in array or not using `in_array`

```
$supported = ['md', 'txt', 'html', 'pdf'];

function get_extension($name, $supportedExtns){
    $extn = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($extn, $supportedExtns))
        return true;
    return false;
}


if(get_extension("spencer.txt", $supported)){
    echo 'extn exists in array';
} else {
    echo 'extn doesn\'t exists in array';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I **will** have multiple functions that need to access the array I added `global` keyword inside the function to make it accessible.

```
$supported = ['.md', '.txt', '.html', '.pdf'];

function get_extension($name){
  global $supported;
  foreach ($supported as $type){
    if(contains($name, $type)){
      return $type;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's doesn't seems to be a good solution, think if you need to use this function twice or more times, It's dependent on global `$supported` variable, Instead pass the array of supported extensions as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public string SplFileInfo::getExtension (void)` function in php, see below modified function, your function not getting supported variable, because its not accessed as GLOBAL

```
$supported = array("txt", "md", "html", "pdf");

function get_extension($name)
{
  $obj = new SplFileInfo($name);
  $extension=$obj->getExtension();
  if(in_array($extension,$GLOBALS['supported']))
  {
      return $extension;
  }
  else
  {
      return "Extension is not supported";
  }
}

echo get_extension("spencer.txt");
```